# How to change login screen background in 16.04LTS?

Tags: 16.04, login, desktop-background

I am a beginner. Is there any easy way to ***change the login screen in linux 16.04LTS?*** I read the other answers already to no avail. Also, I'm not able to bring another file in the backgrounds folder-[image: see this picture to understand better], to do that rename thing whatsoever. please help asap.

regards,
J.

Comment: @JasmineSingh to copy paste and rename into /usr/share/backgrounds.. did you open file in GUI way? try command line `sudo nautilus /usr/share/backgrounds` and from there copy paste and rename.. be careful by entering with terminal command..as you are accessing root folder and files.

Comment: The error occurs because you are trying to copy a system file without `sudo` powers. But to solve the login screen problem you don't need to copy your image anywhere. You simply need to point the login screen where the image already resides. See the duplicate for instructions on that.